# How to edit wicket component to get information about process

Tags: java, wicket

in my form I have textField:

```
                add(new TextField<String>("awayScore", new PropertyModel<String>(value, "awayScore") {

                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                    @Override
                    public String getObject() {
                        logger.info("textField");
                        return super.getObject();
                    }
                }));
```

as you can see I just add logger.

I didnt see anything wrong here but when I run my application I got this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
     at org.toursys.web.PlayOffPage$PlayOffForm$2$1$1.getObject(PlayOffPage.java:135)
```

row 135 contains:

```
return super.getObject();
```

I am really confused about it because without overriding this works

UPDATE:

when I edit my code to:

```
Object value = super.getObject();
logger.error(value.getClass() + "");
```

this code return:

```
 class java.lang.Integer
```

which is really weird because according to compiler this should return String

Comment: Is the awayScore a Integer?

Comment: By saying new PropertyModel<String> you make a *promise* that the returned value is a String. This doesn't automatically convert the Integer to a String.

Comment: hm stupid promise :). Never mind. Thx for answer but I cant accept your answer because you add this just in comment

Comment: but why this works without overriding ? It still return Integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `new PropertyModel<String>(value, "awayScore")` you make a promise that the `awayScore` in your `value` is a `String`. The compiler can't verify your claim and there's no automatic conversion.

In `AbstractPropertyModel` the method `getObject` is defined to return a `T` which will get replaced by `Object`. That's the reason it still works. As soon as you override the method to return `String` the cast will fail.